# Adding a new file:line format for gF for a given file type

Tags: neovim, substitute

I use `gF` a good amount when getting to the bottom of compilation errors in different tech stacks. With Dart/Flutter, I'm getting the error messages in the following format:

```
lib/main.dart:58:34: Error: 'FooStates' isn't a type.
          ChangeNotifierProvider<FooStates>(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
Try again after fixing the above error(s).
```

placing the cursor on the path and running `gF` results in a `E447: Cannot find file "lib/main.dart:58:34" in path` error, which is to be expected. The help says:

```
[count]gF       Same as "gf", except if a number follows the file
            name, then the cursor is positioned on that line in
            the file.
            The file name and the number must be separated by a
            non-filename (see 'isfname') and non-numeric
            character. " line " is also recognized, like it is
            used in the output of `:verbose command UserCmd`
            White space between the filename, the separator and
            the number are ignored.
            Examples:
                eval.c:10 ~
                eval.c @ 20 ~
                eval.c (30) ~
                eval.c 40 ~
```

From what I can understand I can add a "filter" to the strings passed to `gF`, so that when no file is matched, a substitution is performed and the modified string is matched again against the files in the workspace.

I can't seem to get the correct invocation for it though. Here's what I tried:

```
autocmd FileType log setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname, ':\\d+$', '', '')
```

This spits out the following error when trying to open a `log` type buffer:

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Autocommands for "__FLUTTER_DEV_LOG__":                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
E5108: Error executing lua ...vim/plugged/flutter-tools.nvim/lua/flutter-tools/log.lua:104: Vim(setlocal):E518: Unknown option: ':\\d+$',
```

When I skip the per-filetype logic and add something like this to `init.vim`:

```
:set includeexpr=smagic(v:fname,':[0-9]+$','','g')
```

it just doesn't seem to have any effect on `gF` - the `file.ext:line:column` format is still not recognized

Comment: The `Unknown option: ':\\d+$',` part is because you can't have spaces in a `:set` or `:setlocal` command. If you need spaces in the value of an option, you need to backslash escape them. (This gets very tricky in an `autocmd`, so I won't even try to guess what the right syntax for it would be.)

Comment: Using `let &l:includeexpr = …` is thus much nicer, but you may have two levels of strings :)

Answer (score 2):

Since @filbranden have a good answer in comments for the `Unknown option: ':\\d+$',` part. I'm going to do my best to answer the second one.

> placing the cursor on the path and running gF results in a E447: Cannot find file "lib/main.dart:58:34" in path error

This error gives us a clue that the editor try to open a file, which path was "lib/main.dart:58:34". Let's try to ask the problem to Neovim by the following command.

```
:echo substitute("lib/main.dart:58:34", ':\\d+$', '', '')
```

As you can see. The result would be `lib/main.dart:58:34`. From here, We know it's likely a pattern matching problem.

The [options.txt](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/0124a7bfa9e27796e561cb0b3a045b9327bf7077/runtime/doc/options.txt#L129) says

```
                                                        *option-backslash*
To include white space in a string option value it has to be preceded with a
backslash.  To include a backslash you have to use two.  Effectively this
means that the number of backslashes in an option value is halved (rounded
down).
A few examples: >
   :set tags=tags\ /usr/tags        results in "tags /usr/tags"
   :set tags=tags\\,file        results in "tags\,file"
   :set tags=tags\\\ file       results in "tags\ file"
```

and take a look at the section of Multi Items:

```
     'magic' 'nomagic'  matches of the preceding atom
/star   *       \*      0 or more       as many as possible
/\+     \+      \+      1 or more       as many as possible
/\=     \=      \=      0 or 1          as many as possible
```

So we should move duplicated backslash from `\d` to `+` as the following command. Because we don't put the pattern in `:set` for testing.

```
:echo substitute("lib/main.dart:58:34", ':\d\+$', '', '')
```

The result turns to `lib/main.dart:58`. Again, it won't work. Since the output doesn't look like a good file name.

> it just doesn't seem to have any effect on gF - the file.ext:line:column format is still not recognized

Let's write a pattern string against the format.

To change `includeexpr` with fewer characters as possible:

It would be `:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,':\\d\\+','','g')`

Here is my version. It's more readable (No escapes). Enjoy!

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'.dart:.*','.dart','')
```

UPDATE:
If you can't go to the line number automatically after jumping. You should check the option `isfname` and remove colon if necessary. There is no need to set `includexpr`, Leave it empty should works, since the format `file.ext:line:column` is supported natively in Vim.

```
set isfname-=:
```

Comment: But your version gets rid of the line number, doesn't it? The OP wanted to keep the line number, hence `gF`. It's only the column that needs removed.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ok, I got the point and also update the answer for it.